# How to deal with the changes in the Swift programming language?

Tags: discussion, specific-language

I recently re-visited a question in [swift](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swift) and noticed that all code from the question and the answers doesn't compile anymore with the current Swift 2.1 release that comes with Xcode 7.2.

The reason is of course that Swift is an evolving language, and incompatible changes were made between releases (in particular in the 
transition to Swift 1.2/Xcode 6.3 and Swift 2.0/Xcode 7). 
These changes range from

- "minor changes", such as renaming `println` to `print`, over
- "medium changes", such as replacing most global function by
  protocol extension methods, i.e. `map(array, ...)` becomes `array.map(...)`, to
- "major changes", such as a completely new error handling model (`throw/try/catch`).

I wonder if this should have any effect on *existing* questions and
answers. I assume that the answer is **"NO"**, because

- we must not change the question, and
- each answer refers to the code as it was posted in the question.

The disadvantage however is that future visitors cannot copy/paste code
from the answers into their project. Is there any recommendation how
this could be handled?

I don't have the intention to edit all my Swift answers with each
new Swift/Xcode release, but *if* I re-visit an answer (e.g. due to a voting change or comment), is there anything sensible that I can/should do?

***Update:*** I am aware that the problem is not restricted to the Swift
language (as pointed out in Quill's answer). One thing that *might* be different compared to other programming languages is that
many (most?) Apple developers will install only the *latest* Xcode because

- only the latest Xcode has support for the current OS X and iOS SDKs and iOS devices, and
- usually, at some point, Apple doesn't allow App Store submission with
  older Xcode releases anymore.
- older Xcode releases might not run on the current OS X
  (example: [Xcode 6.3.2 can't run on OSX 10.11 El Capitan Developer Preview 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040744/xcode-6-3-2-cant-run-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan-developer-preview-3)).

Comment: Like Quill suggests, if you're going to edit an old answer anyway, I'd just add a caveat à la _"Note: This pertains to an older, deprecated version of Swift, etc."_ and maybe include a link to [the version history](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/RevisionHistory.html). That could help people out.

Comment: "The disadvantage however is that future visitors cannot copy/paste code from the answers into their project." Code Review is about sharing knowledge, not about sharing code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deprecated functions are not a new thing, and not a thing solely to [swift](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swift). You don't need to edit every question to replace `println`, you simply need to understand those questions/answers contain old code.

Python went and changed from `print statement` to `print(statement)`, and the existing questions weren't edited. Granted that the changes from Python 2.7 to 3 were a little larger.

What I would suggest, if you really want to, is that you can edit your old answers and say '*X function is deprecated, replaced with Y function*'.

That is common for some SO posts, but it really isn't necessary here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that completely makes sense. – I am aware that the problem is not Swift-specific. Since I found no existing answer on CR meta on how to deal with language changes I decided to ask about the specific case here. One thing that *might* be different compared to other languages (I am not a Python expert) is that Apple more or less forces developers to use the latest compiler tools. (I'll add that to the question.)  – I will wait if more opinions come up and then act accordingly.

Comment: You do bring up a good point that Apple forces Xcode updates down the throat of developers.

Comment: It might be worth mention that Python includes the version in the tags... But this is something I don't think Swift should do...